# DataTable Row Count is Empty

Tags: c#, list, csv, datatable

I'm attempting to take a list of Contacts that are retrieved from an `OleDB` query, add them to a List and then load the List into a `DataTable`. When I count the number of items in the list it results in the correct number (27000).

However, when I count the number of rows in the `DataTable`, it results in 0. After doing this I want to write the DataTable to CSV using `FileHelpers`, however the CSV file is empty.

This is the code I am using;

```
var listOfContacts = new List<Contact>();
using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(dbfConstr))
{
    dbfCon.Open();
    var dbfCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT ct_id, ct_cmpid, ct_empid,
    ct_pplid, ct_cntid, ct_pplnm, ct_date, ct_time, ct_type, ct_doneby, ct_desc
    FROM contacts", dbfCon);
    using (var myReader = dbfCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {                       
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            var newContact = new Contact()
            {
                ContactID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[0]),
                CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[1]),
                EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[2]),
                PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[3]),
                ContractID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[4]),
                PersonName = myReader[5].ToString(),
                ContactDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader[6]),
                ContactTime = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader[7]),
                TypeOfContact = myReader[8].ToString(),
                ContactMadeBy = myReader[9].ToString(),
                ContactDescription = myReader[10].ToString(),                           
            };
            listOfContacts.Add(newContact);
        }
    }

    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

    dTable.Columns.Add("ContactID");
    dTable.Columns.Add("CompanyID");
    dTable.Columns.Add("EmployeeID");
    dTable.Columns.Add("PersonID");
    dTable.Columns.Add("ContractID");
    dTable.Columns.Add("PersonName");
    dTable.Columns.Add("ContactDate");
    dTable.Columns.Add("ContactTime");
    dTable.Columns.Add("TypeOfContact");
    dTable.Columns.Add("ContactMadeBy");
    dTable.Columns.Add("ContactDescription");

    MessageBox.Show(listOfContacts.Count.ToString());

    foreach (var contact in listOfContacts)
    {
        var newRow = dTable.NewRow();
        newRow["ContactID"] = contact.ContactID;
        newRow["CompanyID"] = contact.CompanyID;
        newRow["EmployeeID"] = contact.EmployeeID;
        newRow["PersonID"] = contact.PersonID;
        newRow["ContractID"] = contact.ContractID;
        newRow["PersonName"] = contact.PersonName;
        newRow["ContactDate"] = contact.ContactDate;
        newRow["ContactTime"] = contact.ContactTime;
        newRow["TypeOfContact"] = contact.TypeOfContact;
        newRow["ContactMadeBy"] = contact.ContactMadeBy;
        newRow["ContactDescription"] = contact.ContactDescription;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(dTable.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

You can see the two `MessageBox` that result in the numbers, am I loading the Data into the `DataTable` incorrectly?

Comment: You still need to add the new `DataRow` to the `DataTable` after creating it.

Comment: Any reason you don't fill the datatable directly rather than converting it from the objects?  Also, for what it's worth `myReader.GetDateTime(6)` and `myReader.GetInt32(0)` might be more direct than your approach.

Comment: Additionally, why bother with the interim `Contact` list if you're just sending the data to a `DataTable`? And, if possible, I would think a collection of `Contact`s would be a preferable way to consume the data, instead of a `DataTable`..

Comment: Something like `dTable.Rows.Add(newRow);` within your foreach loop after assigning the list of items to the new row.  Also, as others have pointed out, you're iterating over your data quite a bit.  Unless you specifically need to make use of both the datatable and the list of contacts, you should really only keep one of these two, especially seeing that you're dealing with a rather sizable collection.

Comment: I'm purely using this approach as I was having issue with the formatting of the Date fields when loaded into CSV. They were formatted dd-MM-yyyy and I need them yyyy-MM-dd. I believed this was due to the `FileHelpers` package as I had tried to convert the Date column in many ways and it just wasn't working. I'm now hoping        `[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")]
        public DateTime ContactDate;` will fix this.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't advocate for this, but you might consider formatting the date as it's coming across in the SQL (unless you can do this in whatever control you're using to display the data?).  Usually you want to leave display related issues for your display, but in this case, it makes more sense to just format the data as opposed to reiterating through some 27,000 records.

Comment: I've already tried that too. I'm using OleDB (data from Visual Fox Pro) and I can't find a way to format the Date in the SELECT query. This also isn't display related issues. I'm converting from Visual Fox Pro datat to MySQL.

Comment: I'm presuming this data is then being dumped to a data grid of sorts first, or is it being directly exported to csv (per the tags on this question)?  The issue might not even be within this chunk of the code, but rather with wherever the data is being displayed/exported.  It's very possible that the date formatting is a default formatting for however you're using it, and might very well be able to be altered at the point of display.

Comment: Visual Fox Pro - OleDB Command - List - DataTable - CSV - MySQL (BulkLoader). That's the order of things at the moment. I know it's probably not the best way to do it but I'm experimenting on getting it working at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the new row to the `DataTable`:

```
foreach (var contact in listOfContacts)
{
    var newRow = dTable.NewRow();
    newRow["ContactID"] = contact.ContactID;
    newRow["CompanyID"] = contact.CompanyID;
    newRow["EmployeeID"] = contact.EmployeeID;
    newRow["PersonID"] = contact.PersonID;
    newRow["ContractID"] = contact.ContractID;
    newRow["PersonName"] = contact.PersonName;
    newRow["ContactDate"] = contact.ContactDate;
    newRow["ContactTime"] = contact.ContactTime;
    newRow["TypeOfContact"] = contact.TypeOfContact;
    newRow["ContactMadeBy"] = contact.ContactMadeBy;
    newRow["ContactDescription"] = contact.ContactDescription;

    dTable.Rows.Add(newRow);  // YOU NEED THIS LINE TO ADD THE NEWROW TO DATATABLE
}
```

Comment: Another way which i prefer is to create the row with `var newRow = dTable.Rows.Add();`. Then it's already added at this point with default values and you can set all fields afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop add this at the end :

```
dTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```